# I want to change the bit depth of an image in R

Tags: r, image, autocad, bit-depth

I have been trying to get autocad to print a georeferenced photo in any format. Every time I get a photo from a private company it will not plot, however, geotiffs of the same format from my local government plot just fine. After testing may different things it could be, my newest idea is bit depth. The bit depth of the governments photos is 32 while the private ones are 24. I was wondering if there is a way in R, since it is the only language I know, to convert any photo types (since I can alter the photo types just fine) from 24 to 32 bit depth either through math code or a function in a package. Thank you.